# Unity | Get backward vector and play turn anim

Tags: unity-game-engine, move, target, direction, turn

Struggling with the implementation of character rotation animation by 180 degrees.

For clarity, I made a Pivot, which indicates the target of the direction, then compares the angle between the direction of the character and the direction of the target, calculates the difference in the nearest angles and, if the difference is greater than 179, plays the Turn180 animation.

Works, but crooked.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyB2S.jpg)

**Problem:**

Since the control of the character and the target are identical, the script does not have time to calculate the difference and gives out values at full turn are not always needed. Like: (-178.6661), (169.8465), (168.1936) and so on.

I'm sure there is an easier way. The only thing that comes to mind is to compare the *TargetPisition* with the *-transform.forward* and then play the reversal animation. But I can't figure out how to do it. I need help with Movement and Target.

UPDATE
I rewrote the code from scratch more carefully, but the issue with the turn remains relevant. The target and the Player are turning at the same time, how do I tell the program that I'm going to turn in the opposite direction and play the animation?

```
    void Movement() {

    // WASD
    
    float Horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float Vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = Quaternion.Euler (0, playerCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0) * new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    //Movement
    
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);
    
    if (move != Vector3.zero)
    {
        gameObject.transform.forward = move;
    }

    //
    
    //Pivot
    
    Pivot.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;
    
    PivotDirection.transform.rotation = gameObject.transform.rotation;
    
    PivotTarget.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position + move;
    Vector3 PivotTargetDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(PivotTarget.transform.forward, move, 10, 0);
    PivotTarget.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (PivotTargetDirection);
    
    PivotArrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, playerCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    
    //

    // ReceivedAngle
    
    var PlayerDirection = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    var TargetDirection = new Vector3(0, PivotTarget.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    
    var ReceivedAngle = Mathf.DeltaAngle(PlayerDirection.y, TargetDirection.y);
    print(Mathf.RoundToInt(ReceivedAngle));
    
    //
    
            
    if (ReceivedAngle >= 180)
    {
        animator.Play("Turn 180");
    }
    
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Why not just make the range bigger? e.g. also rotate if the angle is bigger than 150°

Comment: My goal is if the character is looking straight ahead and the player presses the back button, the character should turn exactly 180 degrees. Right now I'm getting +/- 10 degrees of error, which is not enough.